# google appscript event calendar error message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to create Repeat event from a Google Sheet but I have this error message

> Cannot find method interval(string)

and I don't know why.

```
for ( i = 0; i < l; ++i) {   
column = data[i];
Main =column[11];
repeat = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addMonthlyRule().interval(Main).until(new Date('January 1, 2020'));  
}
```

I want the number in column 11 to set the repeat rule (if it is 3 so the event should be done every 3 months)

Answer (score 0):

The error may come from the `Main` variable. 
You probably get a string from `column[11]` but you have to pass an Integer in `interval()`.
Be sure to cast the string to int with the `parseInt()` function for example!

Comment: thanks. Now I have this message error Cannot convert NaN to (class).In column 11 the data are like this : 12 Months, 6 Months ... So I used 
    var recc =   Main.slice(-9, -7) ;
to keep only the number then I used 
    var reccurance = parseInt(recc);